# What is a modern Internet Cafe software for Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows-10, internet, kiosk, windows-11

I am looking for cyber cafe software that can run 10 machines, it can be free or paid, but must work for Windows 10 and 11.

Required features:-

- Time slot based (30 minute intervals or failing that, one hour)
- Slots can be prebooked or assigned
- Customer accesses desktop through typing in a code (unique for the session slot)
- System must forcefully log out when time has expired (or reboot)

The internet has a lot of dated software back in the heyday of cyber cafes designed for Windows XP that no longer work with newer versions of Windows.

Comment: Sounds like something a library would also use. Have you looked into software for that industry?

Comment: @MichaelKohne I did try all the keywords including library but it only skewed the search towards software libraries. My local library with internet access uses a custom piece of software operating a kiosk, commissioned by the council in a multi million contract covering all their libraries.